# minikube start fails with 'Requested disk size (0MB) is less than minimum of 2000MB'

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm attempting to create a cluster using `minikube`. When I run

`minikube start`

I get the following output:

```
  minikube v1.2.0 on darwin (amd64)
  Requested disk size (0MB) is less than minimum of 2000MB
```

I certainly have space:

```sh
me⚡️$ df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused               ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1   112Gi   82Gi   24Gi    77% 1394770 9223372036853381037    0%   /
devfs          332Ki  332Ki    0Bi   100%    1148                   0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s4   112Gi  5.0Gi   24Gi    17%       4 9223372036854775803    0%   /private/var/vm
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0                   0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0                   0  100%   /home
```

```sh
minikube config view
- disk-size: 2000
```

Comment: Give it a try by appending _mb_ to your disk size: `minikube config set disk-size 2000mb`

Comment: Have you had a chance to try it?

Comment: @EduardoBaitello - Yep, results in the same behavior.

Comment: After `minikube config set disk-size 2000mb` you need to delete the minikube as follows: `minikube delete` and then `minikube start`. At least this worked for me... all the best

Answer (score 3):

You can configurate the disk size of the minikube VM using the `--disk-size flag`.

First you need to run `minikube stop` and `minikube delete` for new parameters to take place.

Specify [VM driver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/#specifying-the-vm-driver) if needed by running the `--vm-driver=<enter_driver_name>` flag.

Finally start the minikube with: `minikube start --vm-driver=<enter_driver_name> --disk-size 20GB` (change the size as you find fitting).

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Hi @OhHiMark, same issue unfortunately.

Comment: I see. In order to go further with this issue we would need more details. Could you please provide some additional info about your use case?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is the following.

Executed the following command(s).

1. minikube delete --all=true --purge=true
2. minikube start --kubernetes-version v1.20.2 --driver=virtualbox

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kevin-smets/b91a34cea662d0c523968472a81788f7

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase docker's disk image size in your machine.
For this setting, you can use docker desktop to increase disk size.
Open your docker destop and then go to setting bar, change it under Resource tab and finally press apply&restart button.

[image]